# Detect iOS Safari "Aa" text zoom level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, safari

How can I detect what the current iOS Safari text zoom level is (set by the user tapping the Aa icon) via JavaScript or CSS?

E.g.

```
100%
85%
115%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: @abney317 No - it didn't work.

Comment: Came across this question and was hoping there was a solution. I find this but it's not quite what we want https://gist.github.com/gjcourt/653079